# VirtualBox - Ubuntu installation

Tags: virtualization

Have installed VirtualBox  - when istalling ubuntu linux the display is cut off on left and right and I cannot see the continue button on extreame right for any screen.  no way to expand it.

Comment: Have you installed guest additions?

Comment: Do you see any scroll bars on the right and bottom of the Ubuntu guest installation window?

Answer (score 0):

You must install guest additons as Arronical says in his comment. If you don't know how to do that, simply do the following:

1. Lauch the virtual machine
2. Put your mouse cursor over the menu bar of the virtual machine viewer. It is a little menu bar in the bottom of the scrren if you are running in full screen mode. Otherwise, look the Devices menu in the top menu bar.
3. Search for the "Devices" menu, click it and select "Install Guest Additions"

[image: Installing Guest Addtions]

4. If you have gvfs or some volume management package installed, you should see a CD icon in your desktop. Browse it.

[image: VBox CD]

5. Open a terminal, in the mount point of the Guest Additions CD and run:

   sudo sh ./VBoxLinuxAddtions.run

Here is a image for reference:

[image: sudo sh ./VBoxLinuxAddtions.run]

6. If you have installed `gcc`, `make` and the `linux-headers`, the script will run without problems, however, if something fails, the console will tell you what to install or do.